# How to find the frequency and utilization of processing cores from Linux kernel?

Tags: android, linux, kernel, cpu, frequency

I have an octa-core device and would like to find the frequency and utilization of each core from Linux/Android kernel. Is there any function or struct that contains this information?

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API on Android with such information. You'll have to read them directly from the kernel.

The cores frequencies you can read from (needs root access):

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
```

And the utilization from (root is not needed):

```
/proc/stat
```

Comment: I actually want to read these values from kernel space and I don't know the function that writes to /proc/stat or the other directory you mentioned. I usually use these directories when I'm running a program in user space. Do you know how I can access the frequency and utilization in kernel space?